# Can't show hidden field JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a form field from the back end, depending on whether an earlier checkbox field in the form is selected.

However the below doesn't appear to work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $move_in_date = $('#div_id_address-move_in_date')

    $move_in_date.hide();

    if ($('#id_address-same_address:checked')){
        $move_in_date.show();
});
```

html

```
<div class="controls col--offset-0 "> <div id="div_id_address-same_address" class="checkbox"> <label for="id_address-same_address" class=""> <input class="checkboxinput" id="id_address-same_address" name="address-same_address" type="checkbox">
                    Have you lived at the property for 3 years?
                </label> </div> </div>

<div id="div_id_address-move_in_date" class="form-group" style="display: none;"> <label for="id_address-move_in_date" class="control-label sr-only">
                Move in date
            </label> <div class="controls "> <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span> <input class="dateinput form-control" id="id_address-move_in_date" name="address-move_in_date" placeholder="What date did you move in to your current address" type="text"> </div> </div> </div>
```

got it working now with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#id_address-same_address").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

    $('#div_id_address-move_in_date').hide();
});


function toggleFields() {
    $('#div_id_address-move_in_date').toggle($('#div_id_address-same_address').prop('checked'));
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: change code `if ($('#id_address-same_address').prop("checked")){`

Comment: also put `;` at end of js statement and closing bracket `}` for `if` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to simplify this quite a bit. This and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) allow you to pass a boolean and set the visibility state (or add/remove a class) to it's value.

Since reading the checked property returns a bool, you can use it directly in the toggle call. No branching statements needed.

```
$('#div_id_address-move_in_date').toggle($('#id_address-same_address').prop('checked'));
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/frkxk3d7/

Comment: Thanks this is a much better approach.  For some reason, this method or the original approach (using if) doesn't work. Beggining to think there is some id issue.  I have added the html now.

Comment: @Yunti I popped your html and the code from this answer into the example jsfiddle and it looks like it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/d8hp4fL6/

Comment: Thanks that's very kind. It wasn't working at first on jsfiddle until I realised I had to press the page load event.  Perhaps that's why it's not working for me.  There is no page refresh in between, these are just 2 fields in a form. I still can't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Note the second field is hidden - but just doesn't appear if I check the checkbox.

Comment: Hmm beginning to think the issue is that the script isn't continually checking the state of the checkbox once the page is loaded.

Comment: @Yunti That'd be a seperate question, but really you just hook up to the change event of the checkbox and rerun that little toggle snippet there in addition to on the page load.

Comment: Got it working now, would be good to know why it didn't work unless a seperate function

Comment: @Yunti That's great to hear! You can mark the answer as accepted if you found it useful to you. I'm not sure what you mean about it not working without a separate function though. I can try to help clear things up for you if you'd like or perhaps ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $move_in_date = $('#div_id_address-move_in_date')

    $move_in_date.hide();

  var checked=$('#id_address-same_address').is(':checked');
             if(checked)
                 $move_in_date.show();

});
```

This should help you

Answer (score 0):

missing semicolon `;` at end of js statement
and to check checkbox status use prop() method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $move_in_date = $('#div_id_address-move_in_date');
   $move_in_date.hide();

   if ($('#id_address-same_address').prop('checked')){
       $move_in_date.show();
   }
});
```